# Trying to understand the boost::beast multibuffer

Tags: c++, websocket, beast

The Beast websocket example stores the data in a multibuffer:

> The implementation uses a sequence of one or more character arrays
>       of varying sizes. Additional character array objects are appended to
>       the sequence to accommodate changes in the size of the character
>       sequence.

When looking at the interface it is not completely clear to me how it works. If I read the descriptions it can be seen as an array of buffers.  But it seems the output is only a single chunk of data. Does this mean the "one or more arrays" are only applicable to the internal structure ?

In the example code the data is read into the buffer as follows: `m_websocketStream.async_read(m_buffer.....`

Does each async_read operation creates a new internal buffer.

If this is the case, how to interpret it at the other end. E.G. how to read it into a std::string or std::vector.

When looking into the sources data() returns const_buffer_type, which is a forward declaration.

For the data member the help information provides the following info, which is not of much help:

> The type used to represent the input sequence as a list of buffers.
>   using const_buffers_type = implementation_defined;

The definition seems to come from the header file boost/asio/buffer.hpp which is included as well. The overall structure however is somewhat obfuscating to me.

I just try to understand how to handle the data as bytes or convert it to as std::string.

Tried the following, but this is also not allowed:

`std::string( boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(m_buffer.data())
,boost::asio::buffer_size(m_buffer.data()) );`

Anyone who can enlighten me a little ?

Answer (score 12):

`data()` returns an object meeting the requirements of **ConstBufferSequence** (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html). `prepare()` returns an object meeting the requirements of **MutableBufferSequence** (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html)

All of the dynamic buffers in beast meet the requirements of **DynamicBuffer**, described in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/concepts/DynamicBuffer.html

If you want to convert a buffer sequence into a string you need to loop over each element and append it to the string individually. Such a function might look like this:

```
template<class ConstBufferSequence>
std::string
to_string(ConstBufferSequence const& buffers)
{
    std::string s;
    s.reserve(boost::asio::buffer_size(buffers));
    for(boost::asio::const_buffer b : buffers)
        s.append(boost::asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(b),
            boost::asio::buffer_size(b));
    return s;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid the buffer copy you can use something like `beast::flat_buffer` which guarantees that all the buffer sequences will have length one. Something like this:

```
inline
std::string
to_string(beast::flat_buffer const& buffer)
{
    return std::string(boost::asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(
        beast::buffers_front(buffer.data())),
            boost::asio::buffer_size(buffer.data()));
}
```

For more information on buffers, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html

Comment: I think there is a typo in the last example. I think it should be beast::buffers_front(...)

Comment: Yep, I renamed the function to `buffers_front` as part of a set of changes to make all the names consistent. I have edited the example code

Answer (score 7):

In the latest versions of Beast, there is now the function `buffers_to_string` which will do this for you in a single function call.

Comment: `static_assert` with `net::is_const_buffer_sequence` fails in this function for `boost::beast::multi_buffer`

Comment: @Mikhail, you should pass the const buffer sequence returned from calling `data()` on the multi-buffer, like `buffers_to_string(multi_buffer.data())`